# Stop bubbling events seems not work on internet explorer in google pages

Tags: javascript, events, event-bubbling

I am working in a browser extension. I am putting some icons next to links in google search pages. These icons trigger some actions and I need stop bubble events after user clicks on it. 
In resume, parent div tags must not know about clicks on these icons.

Next code allow stop bubbling events in all browsers:

```
if (event.cancelBubble) {
        event.cancelBubble = true;
}
if (event.returnValue) {
        event.returnValue = false;
}
if (event.stopPropagation) {
        event.stopPropagation();
}
if (event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault();
}
```

In Firefox works well but in this context not works in IE (version 8 at least). Any idea about it?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (event.cancelBubble) {
        event.cancelBubble = true;
}
```

This doesn't make sense. It only sets it to `true` if it already evaluates to true (in a boolean context). Get rid of the if clause (i.e. always set it unconditionally); setting a non-existant value usally doesn't do any harm (unless you are setting it on a host object which has an ugly implementation)

Comment: Agree, looks like testing for the existence of a function, but this is a property...

Comment: Don't get rid of it. Just unconditionally set it. It's safe to set event.cancelBubble on all known platforms, and that's what IE uses to stop propagation.

Comment: Yes, you right... thanks for the heads up.
Now I am trying unconditionally but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

or try setting it to false, if u use true, the event will fire the code that comes after the event has been fired, when an event has a boolean, it could sometimes mean that u have the freedom to control that event, if u say true, the event may execute other function(s). when saying false the event will not execute other functions, but that only depends on how that function.

coder made his function/code.

but in simple words
"To handle or to raise the bubbled event, a control must override the OnBubbleEvent method.", and thats where u do the opposite  dont override if u did.

if u havent read this yet [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719644(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719644%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and like i said do the opposite.

; )

Hope this helps u out a bit

Laterss!

Comment: Thanks Johnn but we are talking in a javascript context.